# Emulator doesn't show tool tip-tip in action bar

Tags: android

Emulator Google Android version 3.0 Level 11 doesn't show tool tip in action bar.  It should per the Android Developer's web site: "If the action item appears with only the icon, a user can long-press the item to reveal a tool-tip that displays the action item's title."  The same code, same xml does work for Android version 4.03  API level 15. Is there some setting that I may have pressed in my Android 3.0 emulator to turn off the tool-tips? Thanks in advance. Here's the code I'm using.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.flashcard_q_menu, menu);
        optionsMenu = menu;         
    }
```

Below is flashcard_q_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:id="@+id/q_menu_group">
    <item android:id="@+id/fl_edit_card"
        android:title="Edit Card"
        android:titleCondensed="Edit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_edit_card"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_delete_card"
        android:title="Delete Card"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_delete_card"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_add_card"
        android:title="Add Card"
        android:titleCondensed="Add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_add_card"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/flq_prev_question"
        android:title="Previous Question"
        android:titleCondensed="Prev Q"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_previous_question"/>  

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_next_question"
        android:title="Next Question"
        android:titleCondensed="Next Q"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_next_question"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:orderInCategory="1"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/flq_answer"
        android:title="Answer"
        android:titleCondensed="Ans"
        android:icon="@drawable/star_big_on"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:orderInCategory="2"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_up_difficulty"
        android:title="Decrease Difficulty"
        android:titleCondensed="Decr Diff"
        android:icon="@drawable/sym_action_add"
        android:showAsAction="always" 
        android:orderInCategory="3"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_down_difficulty"
        android:title="Increase Difficulty"
        android:titleCondensed="Incr Diff"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_minus"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="4" />

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_shuffle"
        android:title="Shuffle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_shuffle"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/fl_preferences"
        android:title="Preferences"
        android:titleCondensed="Pref"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Does it work in API 12? If so, don't worry about it. Almost no devices still run Honeycomb 3.0 (they're all on 3.1 or 3.2) according to [dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: So the tool tips don't work for API 3.2 Level 13. They do work for 4.0 Level 14 and 4.03 Level 15. I was going to go ahead an pick your answer, but I don't think you put it down as an answer.

Comment: I've formalized my comment; if you want to accept it, be my guest. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As per comments on the OP*:

It's best to check if this works in API 12; the vast majority of units running Honeycomb are on 3.1 or 3.2 (which are APIs 12 and 13, respectively). This information is from the [Android dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). (*Note also that only 2.3% of devices are on Honeycomb at all, so developing for APIs 7, 8, 10, and 15+ should be priority.*)

Additionally, as the author pointed out, the tooltips only work for APIs 14+; this would explain why Honeycomb is not showing them.